# setCallback method is not executing in lightning

Tags: einstein-analytics

I'm new to Salesforce. I'm trying to write an image classification code.But it's not showing result. After debugging, I'm finding that my setCallback method is not executing.
Here is the code of my component

```
<aura:attribute name="files" type="Object[]" />
<aura:attribute name="predictions" type="Object[]" />
<aura:attribute name="rawPredictions" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="pictureSrc" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="predictionMethod" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="phrase" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="imageURL" type="String" />
<aura:attribute name="markupPending" type="boolean" default="false" />

<aura:attribute name="modelId" type="String" />
<lightning:button label="Predict" title="Predict" onclick="{!c.actionBuilder}" />
<div class="slds-m-bottom_small">

    <lightning:input aura:id="fileInput" type="file" name="file" multiple="false" accept="image/*;capture=camera" files="{!v.files}"
onchange="{! c.readFile }" label="Image (max. 5MB):" />
</div>
<img src="{!v.pictureSrc}" />
<!--PREDICTION: {!predictions}  -->
<!--{!prediction.formattedProbability}   -->
<lightning:layoutitem size="6" padding="around-small">
        <div class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-m-bottom_small"><b>Image</b></div>
        <lightning:tabset >
            <lightning:tab >


                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.predictions}" var="prediction">
                        <lightning:layout class="result-grid">
                            <lightning:layoutitem size="1" padding="around-small">
                                <lightning:icon iconName="{!v.iconName}" size="x-small" /></lightning:layoutitem>
                            <lightning:layoutitem size="1" padding="around-small">{! prediction.formattedProbability}</lightning:layoutitem>
                            <lightning:layoutitem padding="around-small" flexibility="grow">{!prediction.label}</lightning:layoutitem>
                        </lightning:layout>
                    </aura:iteration>

            </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</lightning:layoutitem>
```

Here is the code of my controller

```
({
readFile: function (component, event, helper) {

    var files = component.get("v.files");
    if (files && files.length > 0 && files[0] && files[0][0]) {
        var file = files[0][0];
        if (file.size > 5000000) {
            return alert("The file exceeds the limit of 5MB.");
        }
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function () {
            var dataURL = reader.result;
            component.set("v.imageURL", null);
            component.set("v.pictureSrc", dataURL);

            component.set("v.dataType", 'image'); //added

            var dataType = component.get("v.dataType");
            //alert("dataType before upload:"+dataType)
            helper.upload(component);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

},

myAction : function(component, event, helper) {
    var Action=component.get("c.predictImageClassification")
    var base64 = component.get("v.pictureSrc").match(/,(.*)$/)[1];
    Action.setParams({"modelId":"2GKM4XEGJAMW6CXN5GE5YJBT4I","base64":base64})
    Action.setCallback(this,function(response){
        a=response.getReturnValue()
        alert(a)
        component.set("v.prediction",a)
        alert("Action")
    } )
    $A.enqueueAction(Action)

}
})
```

Here is the code of my helper

```
 ({
   upload: function (component) {

    var dataType = component.get("v.dataType");
    component.set("v.markupPending", true);
    var action = this.actionBuilder(component);
    //alert("check action=NULL")  
    if (action==null) {
        alert("Null Action")
        return;

    }
    alert("inside upload+"+action);
    action.setParams(this.paramBuilder(component));
    alert("before callback");
    action.setCallback(this, function (a) {
    alert("inside callback");
        if (a.getState() === "ERROR") {
            component.find("leh").passErrors(a.getError());
            alert("ERROR")
        }
        alert("after callback");
        var result = a.getReturnValue();
        console.log(result);

        var rawPredictions = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);
        component.set("v.rawPredictions", rawPredictions);

        // if we got anything back
        if (result && result.probabilities.length) {
            //special handling for detection visualization
            if (dataType === 'image-detection'){
                component.set("v.predictions", result);
                var ro = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
                    this.generateSvg(component, result);
                });
                var img = component.find("imgItself").getElement();
                ro.observe(img);
            } else { //all other prediction types
                var predictions = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < result.probabilities.length; i++) {
                    predictions.push({
                        label: result.probabilities[i].label,
                        formattedProbability:
                            "" + Math.round(result.probabilities[i].probability * 100) + "%"
                    });
                }
                component.set("v.predictions", predictions);
            }
        }
    });
    component.set("v.predictions", null);
    component.set("v.rawPredictions", null);
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
    alert("END")
},
actionBuilder : function(component) {
    var action;
    var dataType = component.get("v.dataType");
    const files = component.get("v.files");
    alert("dataType: "+dataType)
    if (dataType === 'image' || dataType === 'image-multi-label') {
        if (files.length > 0 && files[0].length > 0){

            alert("inside if")
            var base64 = component.get("v.pictureSrc").match(/,(.*)$/)[1];
            //alert("before setParams")
            //alert("before set base64="+base64)
            action = component.get("c.predictImageClassification");
            action.setParams({"modelId":"2GKM4XEGJAMW6CXN5GE5YJBT4I","base64":base64})

        } else if (component.get("v.imageURL")){
            action = component.get("c.predictImageClassificationURL");
        }
    } else if (dataType === 'text-intent') {
        action = component.get("c.predictIntent");
    } else if (dataType === 'text-sentiment'){
        action = component.get("c.predictSentiment");
    } else if (dataType === 'image-detection'){
        if (files.length > 0 && files[0].length > 0) {
            action = component.get("c.predictImageDetection");
        } else if (component.get("v.imageURL")) {
            action = component.get("c.predictImageDetectionURL");
        }
    }
    //$A.enqueueAction(action);

    return action;
},

//decides what to do based on datatype

paramBuilder : function(component) {
    alert("Inside Parambuilder")
    var dataType = component.get("v.dataType");
    const files = component.get("v.files");
    var params = {
        modelId: component.get("v.modelId")
    };

    if (dataType === 'text-intent' || dataType === 'text-sentiment'){
        params.phrase = component.get("v.phrase");
    } else if (dataType === 'image' || dataType === 'image-multi-label' || dataType === 'image-detection' ){
        if (files.length > 0 && files[0].length > 0) {
            params.base64 = component.get("v.pictureSrc").match(/,(.*)$/)[1];
        } else if (component.get("v.imageURL")) {
            params.url = component.get("v.pictureSrc");
        }
    }



    return params;
},



// image detection stuff


generateSvg: function (component, result) {
    console.log("generating svg");

    var imgContainer = component.find("imgContainer").getElement();
    while (imgContainer.firstChild) {
        imgContainer.removeChild(imgContainer.firstChild);
    }
    var img = component.find("imgItself").getElement();

    var proportion = img.clientHeight / img.naturalHeight;
    if (proportion > 1) {
        proportion = 1;
    }

    var probabilities = result.probabilities;

    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    var svgNS = svg.namespaceURI;

    var leftPos = img.offsetLeft;
    var topPos = img.offsetTop;

    var colors = this.buildColorCoding(probabilities);

    probabilities.forEach(function (probability) {
        var color = colors[probability.label];
        // create polygon for box
        var polygon = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "polygon");
        polygon.setAttribute(
            "style",
            "stroke:" + color + ";stroke-width:3;fill-opacity:0"
        );
        var points = [];
        points.push(
            (probability.boundingBox.minX * proportion + leftPos) +
            "," +
            (probability.boundingBox.minY * proportion + topPos)
        );
        points.push(
            (probability.boundingBox.maxX * proportion + leftPos) +
            "," +
            (probability.boundingBox.minY * proportion + topPos)
        );
        points.push(
            (probability.boundingBox.maxX * proportion + leftPos) +
            "," +
            (probability.boundingBox.maxY * proportion + topPos)
        );
        points.push(
            (probability.boundingBox.minX * proportion + leftPos) +
            "," +
            (probability.boundingBox.maxY * proportion + topPos)
        );
        polygon.setAttribute("points", points.join(" "));

        svg.appendChild(polygon);

        // create text box
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.setAttribute(
            "style",
            "position:absolute;top:" +
            probability.boundingBox.maxY * proportion +
            "px;left:" +
            (probability.boundingBox.minX * proportion + leftPos) +
            "px;width:" +
            (probability.boundingBox.maxX - probability.boundingBox.minX) *
            proportion +
            "px;text-align:center;color:" +
            color +
            ";"
        );
        div.innerHTML = probability.label;
        imgContainer.appendChild(div);
    }, this);
    component.set("v.markupPending", false);

    imgContainer.appendChild(svg);
},

getObjectHighlightColor: function (label) {
    if (label === "Astro") {
        return "red";
    }
    return "yellow";
},

// generates a palette of high-contract colors
buildColorCoding: function (probabilities) {
    var colors = {};
    var uniqueLabels = _.uniq(_.map(probabilities, 'label'));

    var colorArray = [
        '#e6194b',
        '#3cb44b',
        '#ffe119',
        '#0082c8',
        '#f58231',
        '#911eb4',
        '#46f0f0',
        '#f032e6',
        '#d2f53c',
        '#fabebe',
        '#008080',
        '#e6beff',
        '#aa6e28',
        '#fffac8',
        '#800000',
        '#aaffc3',
        '#808000',
        '#ffd8b1',
        '#000080',
        '#808080',
        '#FFFFFF',
        '#000000'
    ]

    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueLabels.length; i++) {
        colors[uniqueLabels[i]] = colorArray[i];
    }

    console.log(colors);

    return colors;
}

});
```

I'm not seeing the alert I set inside setcallback of my helper

```
 inside callback
```

and the alert inside parambuilder

```
Inside Parambuilder
```

is executing twice.I'm unable to find the issue. Can you guide me to resolve the issue?

Comment: Worth noting - in your `upload` method in the helper, you're setting `component.set("v.predictions", null); component.set("v.rawPredictions", null);` before an `$A.enqueueAction()` - which means the values will actually be set appropriate in the enqueueAction and not be cleared out.  It's best to null these out higher up in your method.  Not sure if this will help your issue

Comment: Sorry @Brian, I didn't get. Are you asking me to set `component.set("v.predictions", null); component.set("v.rawPredictions", null)` after `$A.enqueueAction()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you're calling asynchronous code outside the Aura life cycle, so expect unusual behavior. Notably, outside the life cycle, $A.enqueueAction won't do anything until the next time you enter the lifecycle, which would be when a controller method is called in response to an event.

You need to wrap the functions that expect to set/get component values, or fire Aura events/actions, inside an Aura lifecycle. The following change should work:

```
    reader.onloadend = $A.getCallback(function () {
        var dataURL = reader.result;
        component.set("v.imageURL", null);
        component.set("v.pictureSrc", dataURL);

        component.set("v.dataType", 'image'); //added

        var dataType = component.get("v.dataType");
        //alert("dataType before upload:"+dataType)
        helper.upload(component);
    });
```